# How to fix getting always the "No token provided." even when i test with postman

Tags: angular, express, passport.js

Hey i'm kind of new to MEAN stack and i need help with jwt tocken i keep getting the "No token provided." error even when i test with postman Authorization Bearer token-string

this is the code

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports.verifyJwtToken = (req, res, next) => {
    var token;
    if ('Authorization' in req.headers)
        token = req.headers['Authorization'].split(' ')[1];
    if (!token)
        return res.status(403).send({ auth: false, message: 'No token provided.' });
    else {
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET,
            (err, decoded) => {
                if (err)
                    return res.status(500).send({ auth: false, message: 'Token authentication failed.' });
                else {
                    req._id = decoded._id;
                    next();
                }
            }
        )
}
}
```

Comment: Use bearer token with this package express-bearer-token https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-bearer-token

Comment: can you show how you are adding token on postman?? Attach its photo maybe?